# Двумерный ассоциативный массив - цикл

Tags: javascript, массивы, циклы

Прошу пояснить и помочь с циклом. Есть двумерный ассоциативный массив

```html
$msv[0][str1] = "value";
$msv[0][str2] = "value";

$msv[1][str1] = "value";
$msv[1][str2] = "value";
```

как на JS перебрать его и получить значения?

хотелось бы получить что-то на подобии вот такой конструкции (php)

```html
foreach($msv as $id => $msv2){ 
    foreach($msv2 as  $str => $value){
        $msv_id = $id;
        $msv_str = $str;
        $msv_value = $value"; 
    } 
}
```

Прошу помощи кусочком кода! Спасибо!!!

Comment: [`for..in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in)

Comment: за "наводку" спасибо, но js для меня темный лес, только начал интересоваться... тут многое по другому, поэтому если не сложно, пожалуйста - кусочек кода можно?

Comment: Тут больше вопрос, данные уже находяться в JS, и их нужно перебрать, или их еще не мешало бы передать в JS с PHP?

Comment: данные уже получены от php в таком формате

"{
'1':{'дата':'___','Имя':'___','текст':'________'},
'2':{'дата':'___','Имя':'___','текст':'________'},
'3':{'дата':'___','Имя':'___','текст':'________'},
'4':{'дата':'___','Имя':'___','текст':'________'}
}";

Answer (score 0):

Так?

```js
const msv = [
  {
    str1: 'value1',
    str2: 'value2'
  },
  {
    str3: 'value3'
  },
  {
    str4: 'value4'
  }
]

for (let id in msv)
  for (let str in msv[id]) {
    let value = msv[id][str]
    console.log({ id, str, value })
  }
```

Comment: похоже, еще не получилось проверить...
как вообще включить в андройд студии эту консоль?
спасибо!

Comment: Вам для Java чтоли надо код? Вы можете тут код запустить чтобы проверить